# Filtering a specific range of NDVI values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, filter

I have this script that creates a composite image From Sentinel-2 in GEE and filters it for date and ROI:

```
/* Import Sentinel-2 imagery and mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band */
function maskS2clouds(COPERNICUS/S2_SR) {
  var qa = S2L2A.select('QA60');

  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return S2L2A.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}        
 
var S2_Spring= ee.ImageCollection(COPERNICUS/S2_SR)
                  .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-08-31')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filterBounds(Region_Border)
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(Region_Border)});
                  
var visualization = {
 min: 0.0,
 max: 0.3,
 bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
```

After, I calculate NDVI and add it to the collection as a band:

```
var addNDVI = function(COPERNICUS/S2_SR) {
  var ndvi = S2L2A.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return S2L2A.addBands(ndvi);
};

var S2_Spring = S2_Spring.map(addNDVI);
```

Finaly, I select the desired bands and create a composite:

```
var S2_Spring = ee.ImageCollection(S2_Spring.select(["B2", "B3", "B4","B8","NDVI", "NDWI","B5", "B6", "B7","B8A","B11", "B12"] ,["Sp_B2", "Sp_B3", "Sp_B4","Sp_B8","Sp_NDVI", "Sp_NDWI","Sp_B5", "Sp_B6", "Sp_B7","Sp_B8A","Sp_B11","Sp_B12"]));

var S2_Spring_Composite = S2_Spring.mosaic();
```

Then, I use it for supervised classification in GEE. I need to minimize my error in classification, so I decided to use a filter to mask out areas that are not useful for classification.
Is it possible to calculate NDVI over the final composite image *'**S2_Spring_Composite**'* and filter it for a specific range? For example, find and deleted NDVI values less than 0 and more than 0.2?

Comment: Instead of deleting those pixels, why not add classes for water bodies, snow and so?

Comment: Because they are not snow or water bodies. They are solar panels that I am trying to separate from fields around them and have low NDVI values , so it is what I thought could help to classify them

Comment: In that case, create a class for solar panels if there are many occurrences, since removing values could lead to errors in the final result. If you are using NDVI I suppose you want to classify crops/forests, a multi-temporal approach is better for that classes

Comment: BTW `.divide(10000)` won't convert DN to reflectance to S2 products after Jan 22, 2022. The new conversion is (DN-1000)/10000

Comment: Oh I did not know that! I took it form the website https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR, and there was only .divide(10000)

Comment: @aldo_tapia Should I use the  'S2_SR_HARMONIZED' instead??

Comment: Yes, Dealing with products before and after baseline 4.0 is a pain (although you can add a logic test based on Jan 25th for reflectance conversion). But the product you mention will save you time

Comment: Fortunately, my time period starts way after January 2022, so I am working on summer/autumn 2022. So by using the Harmonized collection, all will be as before. Thanks so much for letting me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `updateMask` to mask the values you indicate. You just need to define a mask of the NDVI values you wish to retain in the image and apply it to your image.

```
// Create a mask with the values you wish to retain
var maskIm = S2_Spring_Composite.select('Sp_NDVI').gte(0)
                                .and(S2_Spring_Composite.select('Sp_NDVI').lte(0.2));

// Masked image
var maskedIm = S2_Spring_Composite.updateMask(maskIm);
```

Comment: Thanks. I added what you wrote and it works for masking, but I realized that if I add an NDVI map separately to the script and compare the values, I see differences between the NDVI added as a band to the collection and NDVI map separately. I share my script here with assets. If you use the inspector on the point geometry, the 'Sp_NDVI' band shows 0.04, while the NDVI map separately calculated shows teh value 0.37! Which one is the correct NDVI values? I am confused because the formula for calculating NDVI is the same.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/dff587986b168ffa9ea044d7d97451fa

Comment: The difference is caused by using `mosaic` and `mean` to obtain the final composite. `mosaic` takes the most recent pixels and add it to the final result, while `mean` calculates the mean value of all the unmasked pixels. You might want to take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic